# Exclude node_module/package from production build webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, production-environment

I am working on a project that uses `"webpack": "^2.4.1",`, it is a ReactJS project, I have installed the module `airbnb/prop-types-exact`, I am using this package for development purposes, where I would not want a user of a component I wrote to pass non-existing properties to that component.

I would like to remove this package when I build the app for production. I am using the `Webpack Bundle Initializer` to see the bundle size of `airbnb/prop-types-exact`, it is not that big, but I would like to have it removed from the production build, Is this achievable? With the webpack version that I am using or with a latter one?

I would appreciate any resources or ideas regarding this, thanks.

Comment: Can you specify the package as a `devDependency` in your `package.json`? https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies

Comment: Yes I have installed it under the dev dependencies

Comment: the question doesn't makes sense to me! if you want to remove the dependency in any build you would not be importing it whether production or dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following through an example from this [Blog by Mark](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2017/02/25/webpack-ignore-module/)

And more references on these plugins:
[IgnorePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/) and [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)
I have used the plugins as he did, which are `IgnorePlugin` and `UglifyJsPlugin` and then in the component where I am using the `airbnb/prop-types-exact` package, I am doing a check on which environment I am in like..

```
let exactProps ;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    exactProps = require("prop-types-exact");
}
```

And depending on whether the `exactProps` has a value, meaning the require function has ran, and ,meaning the `exactProps` has the function from the `prop-types-exact` package,
I am wrapping the my prop types with this  function, .eg.

```
const propTypes = {
  someProp: PropTypes.iRequired
}

if (exactProps && typeof exactProps === "function") {
  MyComponent.propTypes = exactProps(propTypes);
} else {
  MyComponent.propTypes = propTypes;
}
```

And finally I export the MyComponent component

```
export MyComponent
```

I am planning to move the wrapping of the component's prop types into a generic module, so that it is re-usable